# Handling null values when using TableAdapters

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset

I'm using a dataset on my WinForms application which is connected to a SQL Server Database. The issue I'm having is when I'm using a table adapter's stored procedures. I sometimes have a long list of parameters to fill, and the problems occurs when a said parameter can be `NULL` and it comes from a row of the datatable.

For example, say I have a `tableadapter` named `taTest` and a `dataTable` named `dtTest`:

```
dtTestRow row = /* some row I fetched in previous treatment */
taTest.GetSimilarData(dt, row.col1, row.col2, row.col3)
```

But then, if `row.col2` is `NULL`, the program crashed with a `StrongTypingException` complaining the column is `DbNull`. In the database, the `NULL` values are handled and processed as our Bussiness Logic dictactes, `NULL` is a possible value.

What I do at the moment is to check for null values before, like this:

```
dtTestRow row = /* some row I fetched in previous treatment */
if (row.Iscol2Null())
    taTest.GetSimilarData(dt, row.col1, null, row.col3)
else
    taTest.GetSimilarData(dt, row.col1, row.col2, row.col3)
```

As you can see, it can get tedious very quickly, if `col1` and `col3` can be `NULL` too...
How can I handle those cases without doing a bunch of Ifs ?

EDIT
Here are more details on the problem. All cols are `int` or `string`. The corresponding column in the database are `INT` or `VARCHAR(X)` (length differs, but it's never MAX). Since we treat NULL values differently, all those columns are nullable.

As for the dataset, the type is the same as in the database, and it is nullable. For ints, I tried changing the `NullValue` from `Throw exception` to `Null`, but I get an error stating that the property is not valid.

For strings, I can change the NullValue property to null and it works fine.

Comment: What Type is col2? What type is the database column? Are nulls allowed in the column? What type is the stored procedure parameter? Is the parameter nullable? What is the CLR type mapped for the col2 parameter of the GetSimilarData method? The question isn't easy to comprehensively answer because a lot of info is missing

Comment: I will edit the question, sorry

Comment: You cannot set anything other than ThrowException if the column is an int (for example) - really need to see more info about how you use it in the table, the stored procedure and the code/parameters for GetSimilarData. Right now you're just hitting an expecting mismatch in that your DB table has and apparently uses nulls in the int column, but that a c# int cannot be null. This means, generally, you need to use something else to communicate a "null" but can't make any recommendations because we don't really know anything about what youre doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to juggle your null handling settings to be compatible with a) the business null requirements, b) the column nullability considerations and c) the parameter nullability for the GetSimilarData method

Simplistically you can stop the StrongTypingException if the column type is something that can be null without requiring Nullable (e.g. a string) by changing the action shown on the NullValue line in the property grid

ThrowException is the only option for primitive types, so it must be handed differently. Add more information to your question

[image]

> As you can see, it can get tedious very quickly, if col1 and col3 can be NULL too... How can I handle those cases without doing a bunch of Ifs ?

Inlining it is probably the simplest

```
  taTest.GetSimilarData(dt, 
    row.Iscol1Null() ? null : ro.col1, 
    row.Iscol2Null() ? null : ro.col2, 
    row.Iscol3Null() ? null : ro.col3
  )
```

You could also establish your own properties on the typed datarow (double click the table in the designer to open the code behind, and ensure you're adding proeprties to the relevant row type) that do the same:

```
public int? Col1OrNull {
  get{
    return row.Iscol1Null() ? null : ro.col1;
  }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
taTest.GetSimilarData(dt, row.Col1OrNull ...
```

It's hard to give concrete advice because the definition of your method/stored procedure etc is still unknown. The approach above will wwork, from what I can deduce based on what you posted (GetSimilarData col2 argument will accept null, you claim, so it can't possibly be an int.. Means your datatable column spec is mismatched with respect to the parameter spec)

---

Note that your Get method seems mislabelled - Get is used for methods that return datatables, and Fill is used for methods that take datatables as a parameter and populate them